# Как решить конфликт между RedBeanPHP и автозагрузкой классов?

Tags: php, orm, redbeanphp

Здравствуйте
кто знаком с RedBeanPHP знает как он подключается и работает, а именно

```
require 'rb.php';
```

и еще подключаю в автозагрузку все классы с определенной директории, а именно

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."classes");
spl_autoload_extensions("_class.php");
spl_autoload_register();
```

в итоге получаю от RedBeanPHP огромную ошибку, а именно

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Class R could not be loaded' in S:\OpenServer\domains\verstala.pro\lib\frontend\rb.php:12974 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: spl_autoload('R') #1 S:\OpenServer\domains\verstala.pro\lib\frontend\rb.php(12974): class_exists('R') #2 S:\OpenServer\domains\verstala.pro\core\frontend\core.php(14): require_once('S:\\OpenServer\\d...') #3 S:\OpenServer\domains\verstala.pro\index.php(11): require_once('S:\\OpenServer\\d...') #4 {main} thrown in S:\OpenServer\domains\verstala.pro\lib\frontend\rb.php on line 12974
```

кто знаком с данной ORM подскажите решение проблемы.